# Why does sem_wait not unblock (and return -1) on an interrupt?

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I have a programme using `sem_wait`. The [Posix specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) says:

> The `sem_wait()` function is interruptible by the delivery of a signal.

Additionally, in the section about errors it says:

> [EINTR] - A signal interrupted this function.

However, in my programme, sending a signal does not unblock the call (and return `-1` as indicated in the spec).

A minimal example can be found below. This programme hangs and `sem_wait` never unblocks after the signal is sent.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sem_t sem;

void sighandler(int sig) {
  printf("Inside sighandler\n");
}

void *thread_listen(void *arg) {
  signal(SIGUSR1, &sighandler);
  printf("sem_wait = %d\n", sem_wait(&sem));
  return NULL;
}

int main(void) {

  pthread_t thread;

  sem_init(&sem, 0, 0); 

  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &thread_listen, NULL);

  sleep(1);
  raise(SIGUSR1);

  pthread_join(thread, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

The programme outputs `Inside sighandler` then hangs.

There is another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853901/sem-wait-not-unblocking-with-eintr?rq=1) about this, but it doesn't really provide any clarity.

Am I misunderstanding what the spec says? FYI my computer uses Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.

Comment: If your goal is to just wake up a thread, the pthread_cond_t (condition variable) is a much more appropriate contract. Looks like you already got the right answer below anyway.

Answer (score 11):

There are three reasons why this program doesn't behave as you expect, only two of which are fixable.

1. As pointed out in David Schwartz’s answer, in a multi-threaded program, `raise` sends a signal to the thread that calls `raise`.

   To get the signal sent to the thread you wanted, *in this test program*, change the `raise(SIGUSR1)` to `pthread_kill(thread, SIGUSR1)`.  However, if you want that specific thread to handle `SIGUSR1` when it’s sent to the *entire process*, what you need to do is use `pthread_sigmask` to block `SIGUSR1` in all of the threads *except* the one that's supposed to handle it.  (See below for more detail on this.)
2. On systems that use glibc, `signal` installs a signal handler that does *not* interrupt blocking system calls. To get a signal handler that does, you need to use `sigaction` and set `sa_flags` to a value that *doesn’t* include `SA_RESTART`.  For instance,

   ```
     struct sigaction sa;
     sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
     sa.sa_handler = sighandler;
     sa.sa_flags = 0;
     sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, 0);
   ```

   Note: `memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa)` is *not* guaranteed to have the same effect as `sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask)`.

   Note: Signal handlers are process-global, so it doesn’t matter which thread you call `sigaction` on.  In almost all cases, multithreaded programs should do all their `sigaction` calls in `main` before creating any threads, just to make sure the signal handlers are active before any signals can happen.
3. The signal could be delivered to the thread *before* the thread has a chance to call `sem_wait`.  If that happens, the signal handler will be called and return, and then `sem_wait` will be called and it will block forever.  In this test program, you can make this arbitrarily unlikely by increasing the length of the `sleep` in `main`, but there is no way to make it *impossible*.  This is the unfixable reason.

   There are a small number of system calls that *atomically* unblock signals while sleeping, and then block them again before returning to user space, such as [`sigsuspend`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigsuspend.2.html), [`sigwaitinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigtimedwait.2.html), and [`pselect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pselect.2.html).  These are the *only* system calls for which this race condition can be avoided.

   Best practice for a multi-threaded program that has to deal with signals is to have one thread *devoted* to signal handling.   To make that work reliably, you should block all signals except for synchronous CPU exceptions (`SIGABRT`, `SIGBUS`, `SIGFPE`, `SIGILL`, `SIGSEGV`, `SIGSYS`, and `SIGTRAP`) at the very beginning of `main`, *before* creating any threads.  Then you set a do-nothing signal handler (*with* `SA_RESTART`) for the signals you want to handle; these will never actually be called, their purpose is to prevent the kernel from killing the process due to the default action of `SIGUSR1` or whatever.  The set of signals you care about must include all of the signals for user interrupts: `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT`, `SIGPWR`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGTSTP`, `SIGXCPU`, `SIGXFSZ`.  Finally, you create the signal-handling thread, which loops calling `sigwaitinfo` for the appropriate set of signals, and dispatches messages to the rest of the threads using pipes or condition variables or anything *but* signals really.  This thread must never block in any system call other than `sigwaitinfo`.

   In the case of this test program, the signal-handling thread would respond to `SIGUSR1` by calling `sem_post(&sem)`.  This would either wake up the listener thread, or it would cause the listener thread not to become blocked on `sem_wait` in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

In a multi-threaded program, `raise` sends a signal to the thread that calls `raise`. You need to use `kill(getpid(), ...)` or `pthread_signal(thread, ...)`.

Comment: The man page for `raise` says it is equivalent to `kill(getpid(), sig)`. Additionally, I know the thread is getting the signal because `Inside sighandler` is printed.

Comment: That part of the manpage is only accurate for single-threaded programs. Yes, it should be corrected.

Comment: @alphabetical98332 If your man page says that, it is wrong. Can you find it online somewhere and give me a link so I can figure out who to context to get it fixed? (I'm not sure why you think seeing "Inside sighandler" proves which thread got the signal. On your platform, `signal` probably sets the process signal handler for all threads that don't explicitly override it. But that's just a guess since `signal`'s behavior isn't defined in this context and can vary.)

Comment: My bad, the man page specifies that only applies to a signal-threaded programme.